# Can not access parameters in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework and scala.I could not access parameters in controller. my function call in view is:

*index.scala.html*

```
<li><a href="@routes.Application.pagination("test123", 2)">2</a></li>
```

*route* is :

```
GET     /image                     controllers.Application.pagination(filter1: String, pageno1: Int)
```

When I tried to access parameters in Application controller it returns null parametres: Function written in Application.controller is:

```
def pagination(filter: String, pageno: Int) = Action {
  println("filter is" + filter)
  Ok("filter is" + filter)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit to:

```
GET     /image/:filter1/:pageno1    controllers.Application.pagination(filter1: String, pageno1: Int)
```

This is because though you have mentioned the generator, but you haven't explicitly mentioned the regex for what is `filter1` and `pageno1`.

Just doing `GET     /image` means you are passing a parameter `image` to the call

```
Get /:st  whatever(st: String)
```

Correcting it should solve the Issue

You can also use [Parameters with default values](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaRouting) like this:

```
GET   /image   controllers.Application.pagination(filter1: String ?= "", pageno1: Int ?= 0)
```

Comment: In your case `Parameters with default values` also will be useful, check my edit